# Are there GUI's to create shaders?

Tags: java, c#, gui, opengl

I have been dabbling around with the shader system of `3Ds max 2012` and the `UDK`. These GUI's are great for testing out things visually. Now I want to create some basic `GLSL` shaders to test some things out in a android project. However I really do not want to go in depth of the core language itself and i'm wandering if GUI's exist to create the shader in a user friendly environment and export the code.

I believe there are tools to convert `HLSL` shaders into `GLSL` so if there is a tool that can export to any shader type that can be converted to `GLSL` in anyway that would be acceptable.